# Quiero determinar cuál es la base que tiene un string en tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Necesito ayuda con lo siguiente:
Tengo que hacer un evaluador aritmético, en donde el usuario elije entre 3 bases(binario, octal y hexadecimal). Luego elije entre sumar o restar.

Una vez elegidos estos 2 parámetros, el programa pide al usuario 2 strings (que corresponden a los operandos de la suma/resta).

En lo que necesito ayuda es para determinar si el string que puso el usuario está correcto en cuanto a la base determinada (para eso está la función checkBase). Sin embargo, no encuentro una forma de determinar que base eligió el usuario para comprobar el string.

He intentado usar .bind('') en los botones de binario, octal o hexadecimal para guardar un número (2,8 o 16) y luego utilizarlo en la función checkBase, pero no sé como guardar dicho número.

Hay fragmentos del código que no tienen ninguna función por ahora, porque no se las he puesto aún.

```
def checkBase(string, base):

    def checkBin(string):
        if string == []:
            return True
        elif string[0]!="1" or string[0]!="0":
            return False
        else:
            return checkBin(string[1:])

    def checkOct(string):
        if string == []:
            return True
        elif string[0]!="0" or string[0]!="1" or string[0]!="2" or string[0]!="3" or string[0]!="4" or string[0]!="5" or string[0]!="6" or string[0]!="7":
            return False
        else:
            return checkOct(string[1:])

    def checkHex(string):
        if string == []:
            return True
        elif string[0]!="0" or string[0]!="1" or string[0]!="2" or string[0]!="3" or string[0]!="4" or string[0]!="5" or string[0]!="6" or string[0]!="7" or string[0]!="8" or string[0]!="9" or string[0]!="A" or string[0]!="a" or string[0]!="B" or string[0]!="b" or string[0]!="C" or string[0]!="c" or string[0]!="D" or string[0]!="d" or string[0]!="E" or string[0]!="e" or string[0]!="F" or string[0]!="f":
            return False
        else:
            return checkHex(string[1:])

    if base == 2:
        return checkBin(string)
    elif base == 8:
        return checkOct(string)
    else:
        return checkHex(string)

def tkinterEntrenamiento():
    oper = ""
    lista = []

    def base2(event):
        return 2

    def base8(event):
        return 8

    def base16(event):
        return 16

    def send():
        txt = str(entryOper.get())
        a = checkBase(txt, base)

    def suma():
        log.insert(END, "Se ha elegido sumar. \n")
        labelOperacion.destroy()
        btnSuma.destroy()
        btnResta.destroy()
        entryOper.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        btnSend.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
        log.insert(END, "Escriba los operandos: \n")

    def hexa():
        a = int(base16('<Button-1>'))
        label2.destroy()
        btn2.destroy()
        btn8.destroy()
        btn16.destroy()
        log.insert(END, "Ha elegido el sistema hexadecimal. \n")
        labelOperacion.grid(row=1, column=0)
        btnSuma.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        btnResta.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)


    def octal():
        a = int(base8('<Button-1>'))
        label2.destroy()
        btn2.destroy()
        btn8.destroy()
        btn16.destroy()
        log.insert(END, "Ha elegido el sistema octal. \n")
        labelOperacion.grid(row=1, column=0)
        btnSuma.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        btnResta.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)

    def binario():
        a = int(base2('<Button-1>'))
        label2.destroy()
        btn2.destroy()
        btn8.destroy()
        btn16.destroy()
        log.insert(END, "Ha elegido el sistema binario. \n")
        labelOperacion.grid(row=1, column=0)
        btnSuma.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        btnResta.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)

    entrenamiento = Tk()
    entrenamiento.title("Zona de Entrenamiento")

    #Elementos de la zona de entrenamiento
    label1 = Label(entrenamiento, text="Zona de Entrenamiento")
    label2 = Label(entrenamiento, text="Elija el sistema numerico:")
    btn2 = Button(entrenamiento, text="Binario", command=binario)
    btn8 = Button(entrenamiento, text="Octal", command=octal)
    btn16 = Button(entrenamiento, text="Hexadecimal", command=hexa)
    log = Text(entrenamiento, height=10, width=40, background="white")
    btn2.bind('<Button-1>', base2)
    btn8.bind('<Button-1>', base8)
    btn16.bind('<Button-1>', base16)

    labelOperacion = Label(entrenamiento, text="Seleccione la operacion a realizar:")
    btnSuma = Button(entrenamiento, text="Suma", command=suma)
    btnResta = Button(entrenamiento, text="Resta")

    entryOper = Entry(entrenamiento, textvariable=oper)
    btnSend = Button(entrenamiento, text="Enviar")


    #Invocar elementos
    label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    label2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    btn2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
    btn8.grid(row=2, column=0)
    btn16.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
    log.grid(row=8, column=0)

    entrenamiento.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sobre las funciones de check

Por un lado, las funciones para verificar que los dígitos están en el rango permitido son innecesariamente complejas. Tomo por ejemplo el caso hexadecimal, que es el más largo:

```
def checkHex(string):
    if string == []:
        return True
    elif string[0]!="0" or string[0]!="1" or string[0]!="2" or string[0]!="3" or string[0]!="4" or string[0]!="5" or string[0]!="6" or string[0]!="7" or string[0]!="8" or string[0]!="9" or string[0]!="A" or string[0]!="a" or string[0]!="B" or string[0]!="b" or string[0]!="C" or string[0]!="c" or string[0]!="D" or string[0]!="d" or string[0]!="E" or string[0]!="e" or string[0]!="F" or string[0]!="f":
        return False
    else:
        return checkHex(string[1:])
```

Básicamente lo que buscas es comprobar si los dígitos tecleados son 0-9 o A-F (a-f también se admite), para lo cual comparas el primer caracter *uno a uno* con cada posible caso, y si va bien, entonces *recursivamente* llamas a la misma función para comparar el resto. Esto es tremendamente ineficiente. La solución típica suele ser utilizar expresiones regulares:

```
def checkHex(string):
    return bool(re.match(r"^[0-9a-fA-F]+$", string))
```

La expresión regular busca que entre el princpio (`^`) y el final (`$`) de la cadena sólo haya uno o más caracteres (`+`) en el conjunto `[0-9a-fA-F]`. Si no es así, retornará `None`, y si es así retornará un *match* que es un tipo de resultado que en este caso no nos interesa, pues basta saber que se ha encontrado. Convierto a booleano el resultado y así esta función retornará `False` si no encaja el patrón o `True` en caso de que encaje.

El uso de expresiones regulares requiere un `import re` al principio.

Si por lo que sea no quieres usar expresiones regulares, otra forma sencilla de verificar lo que buscas es convertir la entrada del usuario en un `set`, que contendrá como elementos los caracteres encontrados (elimina automáticamente las repeticiones), y podemos comparar si ese set está incluido en el set de los dígitos más las letras que te interesan. Así:

```
def checkHex(string):
    return set(string) <= set("0123456789abcdefABCDEF")
```

Análogamente para las restantes bases.

## Sobre tu pregunta

Si no entendí mal estás preguntando cómo pasarle a la función `checkBase()` la base que el usuario eligió. No entiendo por qué no puedes guardar esa base en una variable de la función `tkInterEntrenamiento()` cuando el usuario la elige. Es decir:

```
def tkInterEntrenamiento():
    oper = ""
    lista = []
    base = 0

    # ...

    def hexa():
        base = 16
        label2.destroy()
        # etc...
```

No he entrado a mirar con detalle el resto del código, que me parece en general bastante retorcido, pero creo que con esto sería suficiente para que cuando haces:

```
def send():
    txt = str(entryOper.get())
    a = checkBase(txt, base)
```

ya que la variable `base` de la función `tkinterEntrenamiento()` es visible desde esta función interna, tendría el valor que se le asignó desde el correspondiente valor de botón. Veo por cierto que no haces nada después con el valor `a`, que sería `True` si la entrada es correcta para esa base o `False` si no. Tampoco veo que llames a este `send()` desde ningún sitio (ni tengo claro desde dónde deberías llamarlo). Supongo que aún tienes que completarlo.

## Actualización

Había un "bug" en mi respuesta anterior.

El intento de cambiar el valor de `base` desde una de las funciones internas, como `hexa()`, lo que hace es crear otra variable `base` local a esa función, en lugar de usar la `base` de la función "padre" en la que está incrustada.

La solución es "declarar" esa variable como `nonlocal` en todas las funciones internas que intenten cambiar su valor. Así:

```
def tkInterEntrenamiento():
    oper = ""
    lista = []
    base = 0

    # ...

    def hexa():
        nonlocal base
        base = 16
        label2.destroy()
        # etc...
```

para después usarla así:

```
def send():
    txt = str(entryOper.get())
    a = checkBase(txt, base)
```

En este último caso no es necesario declararla como `nonlocal` porque esta función sólo lee la variable, no la intenta cambiar.

Comment: Ok, hice las modificaciones de la funcion 'send', pero no se está pasando el valor de 'base'. (Por alguna razón, está tomando base como 0)

Comment: @ProgrammerFailure Pues tienes razón, la solución era incorrecta. He editado la respuesta para darte una alternativa

Comment: Ahora si logra funcionar, gracias! Ahora, estoy insertando los strings que pongo a la lista que se llama 'lista' que habia declarado al principio. Hay alguna manera de hacer que continue a otra cosa cuando hay 2 elementos en esta?

Answer (score 0):

No hace falta que hagas un método específico para comprobar los formatos, puedes usar la funcion de python `int`.

```
int("0x12AB", 0) // 18
int("12AB", 16)  // 18
int("12", 8)     // 10
```

Como puedes ver, si el string de entrada viene con el prefijo "0x" no hace falta que especifiques la base, si no, se la tienes que poner explícitamente.

En tu caso, lo que tendrías que hacer es comprobar que lo que devuelve esa función no es un error para casa una de las bases.

```
try:
    my_value = int("0x12z", base)
except ValueError:
    print ("Formato no valido.")
```